# outputting results without bracket tags

Tags: php

how do I output the results while replacing the cumbersome bracket tags?

instead of          [3] => 56531631380

i want             @56531631380& for all items

```
<?php
$f = fopen ('http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page1', 'r');
$page = '';
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
  $page .= $line;
}
fclose ($f);
preg_match_all('#(?:(?<=\bhref="/like_box\.php\?id=)|' .
                '(?<=\bsrc="https://graph\.facebook\.com/))\d+#i',
                $page, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

print_r ($result);

?>


 <pre>
    <?php

echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$result);


    ?>
    </pre>
```

Comment: don't use print_r, in that case. it's intended for dumping out debug data. not for presenting data for end users.

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop to loop through the array $results:

```
foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo "@" . $r . "&";
}
```

Comment: the array is blank for some reason 
<?php
$f = fopen ('http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page1', 'r');
$page = '';
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
  $page .= $line;
}
fclose ($f);
preg_match_all('#(?:(?<=\bhref="/like_box\.php\?id=)|' .
                '(?<=\bsrc="https://graph\.facebook\.com/))\d+#i',
                $page, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);


print_r ($result);

foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo "@" . $r . "&";

?>